# Background scrolling lag

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

[image]

Basically I want the background to move up, giving an illusion that the character is moving down. It works perfectly find when in landscape mode. However in portrait mode, there is a small but visible lag.

The strange thing is when I change the code to :

```
var moveBackground = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -backgroundTxt.size().height, duration: 2)
var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: (backgroundTxt.size().height), duration: 0)
```

Basically change the negative to the positive and vice versa, the background moves up and works perfectly fine (without a lag) in both landscape and portrait modes.

Thanks!